# Can I get my question re-opened?

Tags: discussion

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47168/selling-a-domain-name-what-scams-should-i-be-on-the-lookout-for

Per my comment on the question:  The question has some finite set of answers. Those answers can "be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise." When selling a domain, there is good advice to be had about protecting oneself from scams. I would like to know what that advice is.

Answer (score 2):

I believe John's issue with this question is the "polling, or extended discussion" part.   John tends to close any question that asks for a list of anything.  For more information on why "Big List" questions are usually "not constructive" see [this thread on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136765/is-this-question-constructive)

Answer (score 1):

Questions that solicit a list of answer or discussion are not considered acceptable for this website. Your question clearly expects a list of possible answers if it is a finite list (as most are). It is a much better fit in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No lists of answers? You know how absurd that sounds from coming from the moderator of a Q&A site? I'm not asking for an opinion on a sale, or what people think about an escrow service, I'm asking for documented ways someone could get screwed when selling a domain.

Searching the web for that info comes up with a lot of noise. It would be better to have an answer from a single source (this one).

Comment: I don't make up the rules. It was in the [faq] long before I got here. If you think questions like this should become acceptable here [let the Stack Exchange team know about it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). If they say it's cool then I'm cool with it, too.